# Moving window stepwise regression forecast

Tags: r, forecasting

I am trying to do the following:

1. Fit stepwise regression models using a moving 24-month window
2. At each step, forecast the model-based return 1 month out
3. Calculate standard error for each forecast
4. Plot actual returns, forcasted returns, standard error

My data is as follows (the first is the dependent, the second and third are the independent variables) - I can't get the format to look better, and can't use dropbox at the moment to attach the file:

```
FundA.Return    Explanatory.Variable 1  Explanatory.Variable 2
2.17%       1.96%           -2.34%
0.35%       -2.11%          -2.00%
1.18%       0.29%           -0.09%
2.23%       0.47%           1.35%
2.38%       2.04%           3.73%
1.39%       -0.39%          -1.54%
-0.63%      -0.16%          -4.20%
-2.04%      -0.18%          0.53%
1.80%       0.23%           -1.85%
2.19%       0.66%           1.10%
-0.22%      -1.59%          3.68%
0.68%       -0.12%          -1.96%
0.75%       -0.27%          -1.76%
3.41%       0.52%           -0.42%
-1.18%      -0.75%          3.72%
-0.17%      0.36%           3.49%
1.98%       0.85%           1.77%
1.21%       -0.33%          4.04%
-1.38%      0.17%           -3.73%
-0.87%      -0.37%          0.27%
-4.40%      2.20%           -0.75%
-1.18%      6.31%           -0.56%
0.43%       -1.28%          -2.12%
0.24%       3.11%           -2.58%
2.27%       0.15%           6.85%
0.36%       0.49%           1.94%
0.91%       -0.38%          -1.18%
1.69%       1.18%           3.21%
3.17%       3.39%           3.06%
1.46%       3.93%           -1.74%
```

My code is as follows (edited slightly but I still get an error):

```
library(ISLR)
Returns <- read.csv("Returns New Factors2.csv",header=TRUE)
library(leaps)
P <- nrow(Returns)-24
results <- rep(0,P)
for(i in 1:P){
  stepfit <- regsubsets(FundA.Return~.,data=Returns[i:24+i,],method="forward")
  coefi <- coef(stepfit,id=1)
  pred = model.matrix[P-24-i+1,]%*%coefi
  summary(coefi)
  SE[i+1] = ((Returns$FundA.Return[i+1]-pred)^2)
  plot(FundA.Return,pred,SE)
}
```

I am getting the following error. What am I doing wrong?

Error in model.matrix[P - 24 - i + 1, ] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an R error message without a reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you, @gung. I actually wanted to use a lasso regression, if I can figure our how to do it iteratively. Have you by chance posted on that before?

Comment: The LASSO is potentially fine. I don't know how you would combine that w/ a moving window for forecasting conceptually, though (not in R code, which again would be off topic); you could ask a new question about that. I think this Q can be migrated to [SO] now; I flagged the moderators. GL

Comment: Translation of error message: You haven't even defined an array called `model.matrix` in your code, so you haven't any reasonable expectation that it should work.

Comment: Hi @gung, thank you for your helpful comments. I will try your suggestions.

Comment: Thank you @whuber, that was helpful.